# NSURLSessionDataTask acting suspiciously slow

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing, nsurlsession

I'm getting JSON data from the web, parse it, then using it to diplay pins on a map.

Here is method one, which there is no problem with:

```
NSString *CLIENT_ID = @"SECRET_ID";
    NSString *CLIENT_SECRET = @"CLIENT_SECRET";

    NSString *SEARCH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=gjovik&query=cafe&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20140119", CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET];

    NSURL *searchResults = [NSURL URLWithString:SEARCH];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:searchResults];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.venues = dataDictionary[@"response"][@"venues"];

    [self loadAnnotationsAndCenter:YES];
```

`[self loadAnnotationsAndCenter:YES];` retrieves the lat and lng from the JSON file and uses it to display pins on the map.

I decided to change my code uing NSURLSession. Here's what it looks like:

```
NSString *CLIENT_ID = @"SECRET_ID";
NSString *CLIENT_SECRET = @"CLIENT_SECRET";

NSString *SEARCH = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?near=gjovik&query=cafe&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&v=20140119", CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:SEARCH];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        self.venues = dataDictionary[@"response"][@"venues"];
        [self loadAnnotationsAndCenter:YES];
    }];

    [task resume]
```

NSURLSession is between 10 and 30 seconds slower than the first method. I don't understand why that is. The search string, in this case, returns 27 different locations, if that matters

Cheers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**You need to ensure that UIKit methods will be executed on the main thread.**

The block of the completion handler will be executed on the "delegate queue" (see [`delegateQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSession/delegateQueue) property of `NSURLSession`).

You can accomplish this in two ways: either setup the delegate queue which is the main queue (`[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`) or use

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ 
    [self loadAnnotationsAndCenter:YES]; 
});
```

in your completion block.

Comment: Thanks! This maybe is a silly question, but I'm new to IOS. How can I know my function is a/part of a UIKit method?

Comment: @Nilzone- If you update the UI, i.e. is it one of these classes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

In Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
}
```

Comment: Some explanation with the code might help in understanding the issue and why your code would solve the problem