# popViewControllerAnimated work slow inside NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: swift

```
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
var sessionConf: NSURLSessionConfiguration =       NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConf)
let postData = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
//... there some code to work with Core Data

self.navigationController.popViewControllerAnimated(true) // <- This work slow
})
```

If I'll replace `println("test")` instead `popViewControllerAnimated` just for test code work with Core Data - it's work in one moment and I see "test" in logs. But with `popViewControllerAnimated` after call entire app freeze for about of 20-30 sec. I thought it is because `NSURLSessionDataTask` has timeout interval for request and response data. So I've tried: make `sessionConfi.timeoutIntervalForResource` and `sessionConfi.timeoutIntervalForRequest` for `3.0` but it doesn't help.

I found this [NSURLSessionDataTask acting suspiciously slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21282229/nsurlsessiondatatask-acting-suspiciously-slow)

But I can't add `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` because `UIViewController is not a subtype of Void`. Where I should define a type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve this problem with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22609434/nsurlsessiondatatask-datataskwithurl-completion-handler-not-getting-called). Just convert to Swift.

```
var session: NSURLSession = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConf, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
```